# Dynamic insert multiple rows in SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

I try to add multiple rows in sql table based from form input fileds. Now this code work if one array input is full. But i need to make it for many inputs, for two arrays. This is something like an invoice system, because i use procedure to generate number and then insert in table many rows with the same generated number based of the user input.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
my db connect info
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
$(function(){
 $('p#add_field').click(function(){
 counter += 1;
 $('#container').append(
 '<strong>No. ' + counter + '</strong><br />'
 + '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" />    <br />' );

 });
});
</script>

<body>

<?php
$sql= "exec Create_Number_proc";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$invoicenumber = $row['Ident'];

if ($_POST['dynfields']) {
foreach ( $_POST['dynfields'] as $key=>$value ) {
$values = $value;
$tsql = "INSERT INTO mytable1 (pa_invoice,truck_plate) VALUES         ('$invoicenumber','$values')";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($tsql);
$stmt->execute();

}
}

echo "<i><h2><strong>" . count($_POST['dynfields']) . "</strong>/h2></i>";


}
?>
<?php if (!isset($_POST['submit_val'])) { ?>
 <h1>Field1</h1>
 <form method="post" action="">

 <div id="container">
 <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>add field</span></a></p>
 </div>

 <input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="Submit" />
 </form>
<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Now this code work for one Dynfields[], but i want for dynfields2[] and so on.
Can someone help me here, i stuck on that code. Thank you!

Comment: can't understand what you are asking?what you mean oneinput,many rows,many inputs?

Comment: yes, sorry maybe i must correct my post.

Comment: Please add comments to your code. Add more context to your problem statement to elaborate. Also, point out where the enhancements are required to be made in your code.

Comment: I think in the foreach field i need help, because in javascript part i can make more input arrays.